# JSON int vs float conversion best practices in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I am implementing a simple service with input where

```
{ "a": <float>, "b": <float>, "operation": <string>}
```

Now, I want both

```
"a": 10
```

and

```
"a": 10.0
```

to work. If I only check for float case, I get

```
error: error, message: 'int' cannot be cast to 'float'
```

I get the request and do the following

```
json operationReq = check req.getJsonPayload();

float a = 0;
var intInput = <int>operationReq.a;
match intInput {
    int value => a = value;
    error err => a = check <float>operationReq.a;
}
```

Above code works. But is this the right thing to do, or is this a hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution to your question. You do a type-switch on the value of `j.a`.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main(string... args) {
    json j = { "a": 10.0, "b": 4, "operation": "ddd"};
    float a = 0;
    var intInput = j.a;
    match intInput {
            int i => a = i;
            float f => a = f; 
            json other => {} //error
    }
}
```